# How to make my mysql queries for a friend feed on a large DB?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my mysql table scheme;

1. status table // has statusID, userID,date, subject, date
2. comment table // holds commentID,
   userID who posted, date, and statusID
   that it belongs too
3. user table //holds userID username
   and user photo URL

With that table scheme above, I need to do this;

1. Fast with least amount of DB queries
2. Show all status entries on a page that are published from a user in my friend list (could be up to 5,000 friends)
3. show all comments for each status 
   entry under the appropriate blog
4. show a username/photo URL for every
   status entry post
5. show a username/photo URL for all
   comment posters next to there
   comment

The result I am after is similar to myspace or facebook where it will show all post/actions or whatever from just your FRIENDS only.

You could even compare THIS page on stack overflow to what I am trying to accomplish, consider my post as a status post and all answers on this page would be status post, then under all answers on this page, it shows comments under each one and they all have user info, is there a better way to accomplish this without so many joins and stuff?

Question 1
**Is there anyway better to accomplish what I need?  This is not really fast enough when there are millions of rows that it searches through even with indexes, what are my options?**

Question 2
**Is it possible to modify this to just show the first X ammount of comments on each status post?  And if so, would that speed it up since it wouldn't have to search through as many comments?**

Below the friend List is already in the query, the reason for that is I plan to get the friend list into an Array and store it in memcache or APC cache so it will be 1 less query

**Here is my query**

```
SELECT s.statusid, s.userid, s.statustype, s.subject, 
     s.datetime, c.commentid, c.statusid, c.userid, 
     c.comment, c.datetime, su.disp_name, 
     su.pic_url, cu.disp_name, cu.pic_url
FROM teststatus AS s
   LEFT JOIN teststatuscomments AS c 
       ON s.statusid = c.statusid
   LEFT JOIN friend_reg_user AS su
       ON su.auto_id = s.userid
   LEFT JOIN friend_reg_user AS cu
       ON cu.auto_id = c.userid
WHERE s.userid =1 OR s.userid
       IN ( 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
            10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, // Remember this list of friend ID's
            16, 17, 18, 19, 20 )  //can be from any ammount of ID's  up to 5,000
ORDER BY s.statusid
```

PS) I will start a bounty on this as soon as it lets me

Comment: Do you 'have' to have that Table Scheme?

Comment: Because if not I'd suggest indexing your User/Friend relationships to its own table.

Comment: I'm not really following, friend relationships is it's own table and users table is the main table with account information, friend relation table is millions of rows long because a use can have many friends

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your join is based on the same field being equal to two different values, so it cannot ever be satisfied

```
 ON fru.auto_id = s.userid
          AND fru.auto_id = c.userid
```

You need TWO joins to the user table

```
SELECT s.statusid, s.userid, s.statustype, s.subject, 
     s.datetime, c.commentid, c.statusid, c.userid, 
     c.comment, c.datetime, su.disp_name, 
     su.pic_url, cu.disp_name, cu.pic_url
FROM teststatus AS s
   LEFT JOIN teststatuscomments AS c 
       ON s.statusid = c.statusid
   LEFT JOIN friend_reg_user AS su
       ON su.auto_id = s.userid
   LEFT JOIN friend_reg_user AS cu
       ON cu.auto_id = c.userid   -- EDIT 
WHERE s.userid =1OR s.userid
       IN ( 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
            10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 
            16, 17, 18, 19, 20 ) 
ORDER BY s.statusid
```

Comment: This does get me a photo result for every entry however it is giving me the photo on the comments from the status poster instead of the comment poster, I am so lost now

Comment: I think I might just need to change ON cu.auto_id = s.userid to ON cu.auto_id = c.userid im gonna try that

Comment: Ok great that did the trick now thanks!  Unfortunately this is a big query being ran on a huge DB with millions of rows so it is not as fast as I need it, even with proper indexes, I wonder if there is another way to do this?